# How do I write a custom CSV Reader in python without using csv import?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, file-io

I'm trying to solve a problem from the pyschools website that asks to write a script that reads a CSV file with comas "," as a delimiter and returns a list of records. When running my script on their website it returns as incorrect using a test case of:
csvReader('books.csv')[0] thus returning:

```
['"Pete,Zelle","Intro to HTML, CSS",2011']
```

when the expected result is:

```
['Pete,Zelle', 'Intro to HTML, CSS', '2011']
```

I've notice that the problem has to do with the quotations " & ' but still haven't come up with the right answer, using replace('"','') for the line variable to remove the double quotes does not fix it as it returns as:

```
['Pete,Zelle,Intro to HTML, CSS,2011']
```

where it removes the last quotation mark from some of the words e.g. Zelle, instead of Zelle',.

Below ill provide a link to the exercise, the problem and my current script. Any explanation or help is greatly appreciated.

link:
http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s13-q8

problem:
Write a function to read a CSV file with ',' as delimiter and returns a list of records.
The function must be able to ignore ',' that are within a pair of double quotes '"'.

script:

```
def csvReader(filename):
    records = []
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.rstrip()  # strip '\n'
        if line=='","':
           continue           # ignore empty line

        records.append([line.replace('"','')])


    return records
```

Comment: Try using `items = line.rstrip().split(',')`, then `records.append(items)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was after the CSV file you are trying to read. Sounds as though you need to seperate the fields whilst ignoring any delimiters that fall inbetween quotation marks.

In this case I would recommend the CSV Library and setting the quotation character.

```
import csv
record = '"Pete,Zelle","Intro to HTML, CSS",2011'
newStr = [ '"{}"'.format(x) for x in list(csv.reader([record], delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[0] ]
print(newStr)
```

Will return ['"Pete,Zelle"', '"Intro to HTML, CSS"', '"2011"']

In your function you could incorporate this as below

```
import csv
def csvReader(filename):
    records = []
    for line in open(filename):
        line = line.rstrip()  # strip '\n'
        if line=='","':
           continue           # ignore empty line
        newLine = [ '"{}"'.format(x) for x in list(csv.reader([line], delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))[0] ]
        records.append(newLine)

    return records
```

Answer (score 0):

Batteries are included, as usual, with python. Here's using the standard lib csv module:

```
import csv
with open(path, "r") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        print(f"{row_number} => {row}")
```

If the stdlib isn't available for some strange reason.. you'll need to tokenize each line with 'delimiters', 'separators', and 'cell values'. Again, this would be trivial with stdlib (`import re`). Let's pretend you have no batteries at all, just `plain python`.

You'll need to realize that how you treat each character of each line depends on a "context" and that that context is built up by all previous characters. Using a stack is advised here. You push and pop off states (aka contexts) from a stack
depending on what the current context is (the top of your stack) and the current character you're handing. Now, given a context, you may process each character differently depending on that context:

```
class State: 
    IN_NON_DELIMITED_CELL = 1 
    IN_DELIMITED_CELL = 2 

def get_cell_values(line, quotechar='"', separator=','): 
    stack = [] 
    stack.append(State.IN_NON_DELIMITED_CELL) 
    cell_values = [""] 
    for character in line: 
        current_state = stack[-1] 
        if current_state == State.IN_NON_DELIMITED_CELL: 
            if character == quotechar: 
                stack.append(State.IN_DELIMITED_CELL) 
            elif character == separator: 
                cell_values.append("") 
            else: 
                cell_values[-1] += character 

        if current_state == State.IN_DELIMITED_CELL: 
            if character == quotechar: 
                stack.pop() 
            else: 
                cell_values[-1] += character 
    return cell_values 

with open(path, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cell_values = tokenize(line, quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
        print(cell_values)
```

This is a good starting point:

```
print(get_cell_values('"this","is",an,example,of,"doing things, the hard way?"'))
# prints:
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'of', 'doing things, the hard way?']
```

For taking this (MUCH) further, look into these topics: tokenizing strings, LL+LR parsers, recursive descent, shift-reduce parsers.